Simplify the way of grep specific field values
Everyone, my data. Frame is like:
      id ACODE_ICD9_1 ACODE_ICD9_2 ACODE_ICD9_3
    <int>       <char>       <char>       <char>
 1:    20          463         4660         4720
 2:    27        42731        43490        73300
 3:    48        40210         2722        43410
 4:    52        40210        43410         4139
 5:    57        40210        43410         4139
 6:    58        40210        43410         4139
 7:    59         4660         7242         7245
 8:    77        40210         7804         7840
 9:    98        42731         7804        78650
10:   101          463         4269        78052
....

I want to grep disease by my ICD code,
Is there any other way to simplify it?
Because I have many diseases
It will make my program more complicated and less readable.
Thank!
disease <- data %>%
  mutate(AF = ifelse(grepl("^42731", ACODE_ICD9_1) |
                       grepl("^42731", ACODE_ICD9_2) |
                       grepl("^42731", ACODE_ICD9_3), 1, 0),
         HTN = ifelse(grepl("^401|^402|^403|^404|^405", ACODE_ICD9_1) |
                            grepl("^401|^402|^403|^404|^405", ACODE_ICD9_2) |
                            grepl("^401|^402|^403|^404|^405", ACODE_ICD9_3), 1, 0),
         DM = ifelse(grepl("^250", ACODE_ICD9_1) |
                           grepl("^250", ACODE_ICD9_2) |
                           grepl("^250", ACODE_ICD9_3), 1, 0)...


 df %>% 
    mutate(AF = +if_any(-id, ~str_detect(., "^42731")), 
           HTN = +if_any(-id, ~grepl("^40[1-5]", .)), 
           DM = +if_any(-id, ~grepl("^250", .)))

     id ACODE_ICD9_1 ACODE_ICD9_2 ACODE_ICD9_3 AF HTN DM
1:   20          463         4660         4720  0   0  0
2:   27        42731        43490        73300  1   0  0
3:   48        40210         2722        43410  0   1  0
4:   52        40210        43410         4139  0   1  0
5:   57        40210        43410         4139  0   1  0
6:   58        40210        43410         4139  0   1  0
7:   59         4660         7242         7245  0   0  0
8:   77        40210         7804         7840  0   1  0
9:   98        42731         7804        78650  1   0  0
10: 101          463         4269        78052  0   0  0


I like the "+" here, learned something new!

Thank! It really helped me reduce repetitive problems!

Can I ask why 1/0 does not appear? @Onyambu

@Bruce what do you mean? I see 1/0 in the solution

What I'm curious about is that I didn't see the special setting ifelse..1, 0) but why the result can appear 1,0? Thank you

@Bruce i used coercion. A TRUE is a 1 and a FALSE is a zero. Eg try runningas.numeric(c(TRUE,FALSE)) and you will see what i mean. The + sign coerces the logical to numeric

Thank you, I learned a new skill!

pats <- c(AF = "^42731", HTN = "^40[1-5]", DM = "^250")

df %>%
   pivot_longer(-id,names_transform = ~'col')%>%
   pivot_wider(values_fn = ~list(map(pats, ~+any(grepl(., .y)), .y=.x)))%>%
   unnest_wider(col, names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 10 × 4
      id col_AF col_HTN col_DM
   <int>  <int>   <int>  <int>
 1    20      0       0      0
 2    27      1       0      0
 3    48      0       1      0
 4    52      0       1      0
 5    57      0       1      0
 6    58      0       1      0
 7    59      0       0      0
 8    77      0       1      0
 9    98      1       0      0
10   101      0       0      0


I also thought about using use melt to convert my DF.
